# Migration For a Modular System

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, module, migration

I want to create a modular system.I have a problem about concept of migration in my project.
I need a series principle about create Modules and do migration. For example assume I am creating a PersonService Module and create database according to Models Of this module, then in next Version of this module I must change a model of it.I will sale new module to customer and then the customer's database must be updated according to new model. This process must do automatically. But my questions Are:

How can I migrate my database Automatically in customer system?

What principle is important to create module and database?

can customer update database,If customers want to install old version of module ?

------------------------EDIT-------------------------------
what model is better to use?Code-First?Database-First?Or....?

Do I corrupt customer's data with Automatic migration?

thank again

Comment: Please stop using signatures on your post. Your userbox already does that.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the most recent version of your application using Automatic Database Migrations to the customer and upon the next run it will update provided you have Automatic Migrations enabled in your configuration.cs file in the Migrations folder.  If you have any logic depending on these fields or tables though you need to be sure to populate data during the migration or disable that logic until after data has been populated some how.

To add on to this if you want them to always begin with a baseline database during the initial install you need to enable migrations at that point before you add existing fields or tables to your model, and therefore your database.  If you update the model and want to back date the install to a previous model version you are out-of-luck unless you build extensive code to revert to a previous migration that you never created.

Comment: Thank you Kadumel, But I study about Auto migration in EF and most of the people think that this is a not safe method, can you introduce me a safe method to migration,Can I do Migration in my code?

Comment: I have been using this method for over a year and never had a problem.  Not sure of a more safe method